# Loading fonts from the server

Tags: php, fonts

I have a PHP that is loading fonts from the server in order to write text on images.

All the examples of loading fonts that I've seen in [the manual](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/index.php) or in searches thus far, explicitly name the font (e.g. `Arial.ttf`).  My PHP currently uses a font that is in the same directory, but I'd like to make the PHP more (easily) portable by not forcing the person deploying it, to include a font file.  As such, I would like to have the PHP use fonts that are *already installed* on the server.

Is there a facility in (core<sup>1</sup>) PHP to determine what fonts are installed on the server?  If not, is there a way to get the server to load a logical font (Serif, Sans-Serif, Monospaced etc.)?

1. Note: PHP APIs that can do the above are of no interest.  It would require uploading/installing the API, and that defeats the 'make it easy' intent.  Only solutions that work with core PHP would be of use.

Comment: That's not more portable, that's less portable. Never assume any font is pre-installed on a server, especially servers with ssh access only, where system level fonts are just clutter. If your application relies on a specific font, either bundle it with it, or if the license of that font does not allow it, tell people they can edit an `.ini` file or something to set the location of the font that should be used.

Comment: I can certainly do that. PHP core doesn't use fonts (it has no idea what to do with them) but extensions like ImageMagic, pdf generators, etc. can work with them. If the important part is that they font is used on the client in the browser, then that's a webfont location issue, not a PHP issue really.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That approach would likely make things less portable, rather than more portable: you can't really rely on fonts existing on a given system, but more importantly, given that a lot of PHP installs are on things like SSH-only VPS or shared hosting services, the odds that there are any system fonts available at all are pretty low (no GUI means the fonts are typically just clutter).

If your application relies on a specific font, either bundle it with your release, or if the font license does not allow that (which will definitely be true for Arial, which is owned by Microsoft), your release docs can tell people they have to drop in the file themselves, into a specific directory (e.g. `./resources/fonts`) or let your scripts fetch the font based on a location from the enviroment or an `.ini` file or something, allowing people to point to wherever their local copy of that font exists.

That said, PHP itself doesn't use fonts (it has no idea what to do with them) but PHP extensions for work-on-the-server like ImageMagic, pdf generators, etc. can certainly work with them.

On the other hand, if the important part is that the font gets loaded correctly in the browser, when users invoke your PHP script(s) and they get sent a webpage through which to interact with your code base, then that's a webfont location issue (just make sure the page code PHP generates points to a resolvable URL), rather than a PHP issue.

As a counterpoint to the "*PHP APIs that can do the above are of no interest. It would require uploading/installing the API, and that defeats the 'make it easy' intent*" statement: PHP uses [PEAR](http://pear.php.net) for package management. It's usually a matter of ["pear install dependencyname"](http://pear.php.net/manual/en/guide.users.commandline.installing.php) and done, so there's not really anything hard or even inconvenient about that.

Comment: Thanks especially for the clarification in the final paragraph.  Seems I was making a number of incorrect assumptions!